# Error: Cannot find module ' gulp-sass'

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm having trouble getting gulp to read my modules.

Initially I had a working system.

I then upgraded to with NVM (I removed everything installed with Brew first)

Here's what I have now:

```
"node: v6.11.2"
"npm: 3.10.10"
"nvm"
```

and I have a gulpfile which used to work, but I also upgraded my modules, and I have installed locally in my project:

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-pug": "^3.3.0",
"gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
```

globally for this version of node I do have:

```
gulp-cli@1.4.0
jshint@2.9.5
npm@3.10.10
```

in a simple gulpfile running: gulp would work successfully, but introducing other modules is where I started getting issues.

In my gulpfile I have for example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var sass = require(' gulp-sass'),
prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
minifycss = require('gulp-clean-css'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
rename = require("gulp-rename");

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(src.sass)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(prefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(src.css))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(src.css))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

..locally running any command like `gulp sass` would produce:

```
Error: Cannot find module ' gulp-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myusername/sites/projectname/gulpfile.js:25:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I've removed the node_modules, removed the dependancies in package.json, reinstalled each local module

Comment: Does `/Users/myusername/sites/projectname/node_modules/gulp-sass` exist?

Comment: looks like you have a space in require(' gulp-sass')

Comment: @SLaks Yes, gulp-sass is located:
`/Users/myusername/sites/projectname/node_modules/gulp-sass`

Answer (score 1):

' gulp-sass' should be 'gulp-sass'

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly how terminal prints it, with the space. I kept it in tact it might be relevant

Comment: It is relevant, in your require, you are using var sass =  require(' gulp-sass') instead of var sass = require('gulp-sass')

Comment: Ok let me check that, I think with all the troubleshooting and upgrading/removing of stuff I just missed that typo. That typo cost me 3 hours of looking around elsewhere.

Comment: It happens to the best of us

Comment: DOH how humiliating, a simple type got the best of me. Thank you for taking time to have a look at this issue, your help is appreciated.

Comment: I have a rather long and convoluted gulp file which need's maintenance. Looking at my question, the error is so clear.  In my gulpfile it's not ! Thanks Link0352 thanks

Comment: glad i could help ;D

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting a package with an additional space in the beginning of the package name. Remove the space and try it again.

```
var sass = require(' gulp-sass'),
```

should be

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass'),
```

Comment: that worked, I missed that completely. Thank you for having the time to look & post advice.